# error when try to incorporate target data from SKLEARN in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a matrix to evaluate how different features impact the data set's target. Here I use scikit-learn's breast cancer data. My code is below but the result shows an error, I could not figure out how to fix it.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import sklearn.datasets
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
WBC_dataset = load_breast_cancer()

WBC_df = pd.DataFrame(
data= np.c_[WBC_dataset['data'],WBC_dataset['target']],
columns= np.append(WBC_dataset['feature_names'], ['Condition']))
cols = WBC_dataset.columns.drop('Condition')
WBC_df[cols] = WBC_df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
g = sns.pairplot(WBC_df, hue='Condition')
```

Here is the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    104         try:
--> 105             return self[key]
    106         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'columns'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-1123cb0b25bb> in <module>
      9 data= np.c_[WBC_dataset['data'],WBC_dataset['target']],
     10 columns= np.append(WBC_dataset['feature_names'], ['Condition']))
---> 11 cols = WBC_dataset.columns.drop('Condition')
     12 WBC_df[cols] = WBC_df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
     13 g = sns.pairplot(WBC_df, hue='Condition')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    105             return self[key]
    106         except KeyError:
--> 107             raise AttributeError(key)
    108 
    109     def __setstate__(self, state):

AttributeError: columns
```

Answer (score 0):

WBC_df is not a dataframe, it is a dict containing multiple values. Check  the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html).

```
data = load_breast_cancer()

WBC_df = pd.DataFrame(data.data,columns = data.feature_names)
```

Comment: thanks, does this step not convert it to a data frame? if this is the error what else I should do?

WBC_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data= np.c_[WBC_dataset['data'],WBC_dataset['target']],
    columns= np.append(WBC_dataset['feature_names'], ['Condition']))

Comment: @hw21 just copy my code, I have already converted it to a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The WBC dataset has non numbers in it that need removing before you pass it to sklearn

By default if you pass these null values to pandas it will create a column with  type object.

The easiest way to fix this is at import using pandas to clean it up

```py
## creating a custom missing value list
missing_values = ["NA","N/a",np.nan,"?"]


l1 = pd.read_csv("../../DataSets/Breast cancer dataset/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data",
    header=None,na_values=missing_values, 
    names=['id','clump_thickness','uniformity_of_cell_size','uniformity_of_cell_shape','marginal_adhesion','single_epithelial_cell_size','bare_nuclei','bland_chromatin','normal_nucleoli','mitoses','diagnosis'])

l1 = l1.dropna()

### 'bare_nuclei' is the column with 16 occurrences of "?" in it. so this removes the ? rows,
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!